# Select cleaned Adress Data in an Database

Tags: couchdb

I have 80.000.000 Entries about Persons. They are built up like:
Max;Mustermann;Examplestreet;50;9900;City

88000 is one ZIP Code, 8800 Zip Codes exist.

I want to find out the entry based on Street/Housenumber/ZIP/City as fast as possible.

**The idea:**
Setting up 88 Databases for the first 2 numbers of the ZIP code. In this case its 99.
In the Database i use the first 2 letters for the Street selection and create a table for that.
In this Case EX.
If i assume that the DB 99 has max 2.000.000 Database entries, EX will maximum have 100.000.

How can i find entries fast in this 100.000 ?

Comment: What is the data about - all german citizen? How do you got that data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the right idea what a database actually is? Frankly, your idea with setting up 88 databases doesn't sound like it.

A regular approach to your problem would be splitting the CSV data into regular columns (first_name, last_name etc.) and then using an index on those columns to find data reasonably quickly.